# slick carousel in grid mode cutting off bottom of second row

Tags: slick.js

I'm using slick carousel (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

I have it set for 2 rows with 3 images per row. The trouble is, the second row is getting cut off right through the middle of each image.

Is this some known bug? Anything I can do?

html:

```
    <div class="slick_slideshow" id="slideshow_houses">
    <div>
        <img src="img/slideshow_houses/image1.jpg" class="slideshow_houses_image" />
        <div class="slick-credit">credit1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/slideshow_houses/image2.jpg" class="slideshow_houses_image" />
        <div class="slick-credit">credit2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/slideshow_houses/image3.jpg" class="slideshow_houses_image" />
        <div class="slick-credit">credit3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/slideshow_houses/image4.jpg" class="slideshow_houses_image" />
        <div class="slick-credit">credit4</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/slideshow_houses/image5.jpg" class="slideshow_houses_image" />
        <div class="slick-credit">credit 5 </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/slideshow_houses/image6.jpg" class="slideshow_houses_image" />
        <div class="slick-credit">credit 6</div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end slideshow -->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#slideshow_houses').slick({
    rows: 2,
    slidesPerRow: 3

    });
```

Comment: Do you have the slideshow in a containing `div`?  Maybe it has `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson: Can you add that as an answer? That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have looks fine.  Going by the comments, you had a `div` that contained the slideshow that had `overflow:hidden`.  In general, any time you have cut-off content you should check any parent `div` for `overflow:hidden`.